# Graphing inequalities, not ">" or "<", but "≠"; graphing complex numbers

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, graphing-functions

For simplicity, we'll use $y \neq x$.

$x$: ($±∞$) ($\mathbb{R}$)

$y$: ($±∞$) ($\mathbb{R}$)

$z$: ($±∞$) ($\mathbb{C}$)

I've learned that $y > x$ would be graphed as:
[$y > x$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3YUe.png)
and y < x:
[$y < x$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr48F.png)

but, I have yet to see $y \neq x$. I assume it would be graphed with a dotted line as it cannot actually be equal to $x$, and that it would be both at the same time.
Would this accurately show the inequal sign? "$\neq$" [$y \neq x?$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFH2h.png)

**Would give complex solutions too?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your attached image, the graph of $y \neq x$ is all of $\mathbb R^2$ outside of the line where $y=x$.

[image]

The dark grey background color represents where $y\neq x$. It would extend to infinity in both the $x$ and $y$ directions. The dotted line represents where $y=x$ and is not part of the graph.

Comment: Thank you; properly answered 2D question. Updated to 3D now.

Comment: With your change, the graph would be all of $\mathbb R^3$ except the line $y=x$. The line $y=x$ would lie in a $2D$ plane which only contains the x-axis and y-axis. Assuming that the $z$-axis is complex numbers (which is sort of strange in comparison to the standard Cartesian plane in three coordinates), it would produce complex solutions.

Comment: @Red Does the new comment answer the updated question in $3D$? You would certainly obtain complex solutions (assuming that the third axis in the plane wasn't the typical z-axis in Cartesian coordinates. Instead, the z-axis contains only imaginary numbers).

Answer (score 0):

It would be everything BUT the dotted line though it is not common to graph relations involving $\neq$.

Think as follows $y=x$ describes all the points on that dotted line that is the set

$$
\{(x,y)\mid x=y,\quad  x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}
$$

$y\neq x$ would be the complement of that so all the points for which $y\neq x$

$$
\{(x,y)\mid x\neq y,\quad x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}
$$

which are all the points "outside" that dotted line, the whole plain with the line $y=x$ removed.

Hope this helped